# How to ignore all words containing accents(Non English words)?

Tags: java, regex

I am creating a Java application were i have a paragraph that i want to grab words from it. I want to write a Regular expression to grab only English words and ignore any words having accents inside them(Having 1 or more non English letters).

Example: berøres af eller er afgørende for TEAM

**Should i use \p{M} or what ?**

Comment: English words have accent marks in them.  Sheesh! Not very learnèd, eh?

Comment: many non-English words don't have accent marks in them.

Comment: [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic#English) words can have accents and punctuation.  Contractions ("don't", "can't"), loan words ("naïve", "café"), compound words "fire-fighter", and proper names ("Zöe") are examples.

Comment: If you want to identify English words, the best place to start is with a list of English words : [`/usr/share/dict`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_%28Unix%29).

Comment: You're all oh-so smart and useful. Surely Brad now knows how to filter words that have special symbols in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match all words containing the letters A-Z.

```
(?:^|\s)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s|$)
```

Some flavors of regex will match `\b` on the accented characters. Because of that, you'll need to add punctuation to the lookahead if that is a requirement.